# Selenium webdriver script not able to log in into magento Panel

Tags: magento, selenium

I am trying to log in to Magento Admin panel via Selenium web Driver script but its not working .

It identifies login button and clicks on login button but it is not getting in to next page once log in successful.

```
userid : magadmin
Password : Lean5226
```

when you try it with iDE it is working

```
Website :
54.201.104.110/magento/env-ee/index.php/admin
```

Here is below script :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:/ChromeDriver/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(); 
    System.out.println("Fire fox started");
    String baseUrl = "http://54.201.104.110/";
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/magento/env-ee/index.php/admin/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("magadmin");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("login")).sendKeys("Lean5226");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    String att=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.form-button")).getAttribute("value");
    System.out.println(att);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.form-button")).click();
    System.out.println("Waiting");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.close();
```

Comment: Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: So you can see the webpage loading? When does the browser close?

Answer (score 0):

This post is a little old, but in the event that other people find it interesting you can do this using Magium with a fairly simple command.  The following code is from one of the blog posts on [logging in to the Magento admin IU](http://magiumlib.com/blog/logging-in-to-the-magento-admin-ui/)

```
class LoginTest extends \Magium\Magento\AbstractMagentoTestCase
{
    public function testLogin()
    {
        $this->getAction(\Magium\Magento\Actions\Admin\Login\Login::ACTION)->login();
    }
}
```

There is some additional information on how to configure it on the blog post.